# PHP WCF integration

Tags: php, wcf

Is it true that if I want to support php clients access my service, I must have a basic http endpoint.  Is this because php still only supports soap 1.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know (been two years since I used PHP) this is still the case.

If the client application will be build using PHP's built-in SoapClient class you have to offer an endpoint which uses basicHttpBinding as it conform to the WS-I Basic Profile 1.1 and PHP offers no additional support for any other standards.

I wrote a post about using WCF services with PHP 5 some time ago:

https://github.com/geersch/WcfServicesWithPhp5

It explains how to setup a WCF service and how to consume it with PHP 5.

Comment: Yes, I actually read your post and it was very informative. I e-mailed you too about it actually.