# Web Services on IIS7 Server for Website on Apache Server

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, apache, visual-studio-2010

We have several servers here.

Most of our Web Servers are Windows 2008 R2 machines running Apache and MySQL, but we also have *IIS7 Web Servers* that run SQL Server 2008 databases.

The data I to use in my web reports is partially on the *IIS7 Web Servers*'s SQL database and partially on the *Apache Web Server*'s MySQL database.

A little over a year ago, I was introduced to Web Services in IIS7 when work upgraded from Windows 2000 servers.

I liked creating the Web Service, and I would like to think that this is the way to go. All of the examples I have seen for Visual Studio 2010 (what we have here) only show how to do this with a .Net 3.5 project. If there is something for .Net 4.0, it must be called something other than *Web Services*.

I want to write an application that reads the data from the MySQL database on the *Apache Web Server* and combines that with the data from the SQL database on the *IIS7 Web Servers*.

Then, I need to be able to read that data from a website written in PHP on the *Apache Web Server*.

So, what am I asking? How to proceed, I suppose.

- **What kind of project should I create in Visual Studio 2010?** Reading 1 datatable from each database is easy, but I need to know how to best make that data accessible.
- **How should I access this data through PHP?**

Are there roadblocks that I am going to encounter that will prevent this?

Is there any particular type of services I should be looking into? I'm not sure if I can use a web service with PHP code.

Comment: A downvote and a vote to close with no comment. Lame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web.config file has to be configured correctly for [PHP's basic SOAP class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7344705/153923) to read from Microsoft's WCF. In fact, it seems to need `binding="basicHttpBinding"`.

Here is what I have:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="wcfLibrary.Dwgs" behaviorConfiguration="wcfLibrary.DwgsBehavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="wcfLibrary.IDwgs">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="http://localhost/Dwg/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>
        </service>
    </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="wcfLibrary.DwgsBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"></standardEndpoint>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
</system.serviceModel>
```

One important element I was missing in my WCF project, though, was **WebGet** - because I simply was not able to install the reference to my project.

What I found on MSDN's Blog [Getting Started with WCF WebHttp Services in .NET 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/07/getting-started-with-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx) is that a VS2010 project has to use the **Full .NET 4 Framework**, not the Client Profile like I was using.

Once I did that, and restarted the project, I was able to add **System.ServiceModel.Web** from the list of References.

The **Web.config** section about the `<standardEndpoints>` section was from Step 8 in [CodeProject:Create and Consume RESTFul Service in .NET Framework 4.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor).

### This answer is a work in progress. I will add to it as I learn more.